# How to initialize a variable in a do while loop without passing the value until the loop has closed?

Tags: java, scope, do-while

I've been writing a program that requires the input of a number between 1 and 4. In order to prevent input of numbers outside the range. However the variable keeps passing to another piece of code and causing the program to fail. 
This is the do while loop:

```
        do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a quarter number 1-4: ");
        quarter = scanIn.nextInt();     
    }while((quarter > 5 ) && (quarter < 0));
```

This is the piece of code that runs the variable:

```
        for (int n = ((quarter * 3)-3); n < (quarter*3); n++)
    {
        String sum = fmt.format(monthSales[n]);
        System.out.printf("Sales for month %d: %s\n", n+1, sum);
    }
```

This is the error that returns when incorrect input is entered:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -6
at lab4.Lab4.main(Lab4.java:57)
```

I have tried limiting the scope of "quarter" to only within the loop but then the while clause does not function. How can I prevent the variable from passing until the loop has closed? 
p.s. This problem is part of an assignment and therefore I must use a do while loop.

Comment: First, you allow quarterNum to be 0 or 5 even though you say you want it to be 1-4, and second, your do-while loop will become an infinite loop if the user types anything other than a number. See the almost unlimited number of previous questions about Scanner and nextInt for why. Also, what is the relationship between `quarterNum` and `quarter`?

Comment: Where is the for loop used? what is quarter?

Comment: The program is to compute total sums for one fiscal quarter. quarterNum was a new variable i put in in an attempt to try and prevent the variable from passing (unsuccsessfull, will edit code). how would I go about setting it to continue as long as the input is not 1-4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one thing in your code:

The "do/while" condition seems to be wrong.  If your intention is, as I understood, keep asking the user until s/he informs a valid quarter between 1 and 4, the condition should be something like

```
do {
  // ...
} while (quarterNum < 1 || quarterNum > 4);
```

If I suppose that quarter receives the value of quarterNum in some code in between, the second part seems to be correct and the exception should only occurs if quarter is not a valid value (-1 to be exact).  Fixing the do/while condition it will not be possible any more.

I don't see where limiting variable scopes could have anything with your issue. (and I don't even see what you mean by "prevent[ing] the variable from passing until the loop has closed").

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Thank you that did do the trick! You were correct in the assumption of quarterNum and quarter being equated.